# How can I rearrange this alphabetically?

Tags: python

I want to rearrange a file alphabetically. Also I want the number to be printed next to the arranged letter.

e.g.:

```
a 4
c 5
e 6
f 2
```

here is my code:

```
f = open("1.txt","r")
r = f.read()
print(r)
r=r.split()

line=sorted(r)
for row in line:
    print(line)
```

and here are the results I'm getting:

```
f 2
c 5
e 6
a 4
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
>>>
```

Comment: The top part of my code is a bit messed up, I am new to this websire sry.

Comment: I assume you mean `for row in line: print(row)` not `print(line)`; your other problems are addressed in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the pairs in sublists `map` `str.split` on the file object and call sorted on that:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    print(sorted(map(str.split,f)))
```

in.txt:

```
e 6
c 5
f 2
a 4
```

Output:

```
[['a', '4'], ['c', '5'], ['e', '6'], ['f', '2']]
```

To sort a file alphabetically just getting the lines you would simply call sorted on the file object:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    print(sorted(f))
```

If you want to format the output:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for sub in sorted(map(str.split,f)):
        print("letter = {}, num = {}".format(*sub))

letter = a, num = 4
letter = c, num = 5
letter = e, num = 6
letter = f, num = 2
```

Also why you see `['2', '4', '5', '6', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'f']` is because calling split on .read splits all the data into a single list as split, splits on any whitespaces and when lexicographically comparing string digits to letters digits are considered lower so 2 < a, also beware when you are comparing string digits against each other as `11 > 100 = True` as strings are compared character by character as `1` is considered greater than `0`  100 would appear before `11` in your sorted list, when comparing digits cast to `int`.

If you want to have a max of three scores per user always keeping the most recent, you can use a `deque` with a `maxlen` of 3 and after the initial sort `pickle` the dict.

```
from csv import reader
from collections import deque, OrderedDict
import pickle
name, new_score = "foo",100
with open("test.txt") as f:
    d = OrderedDict((name, deque(map(int,rest),maxlen=3)) for name, *rest in reader(sorted(f)))
    print(d)
    d[name].append(new_score)
    print(d)

with open("my_data.pkl","wb") as out:
    pickle.dump(d, out)


with open("my_data.pkl","rb") as out:
    print(pickle.load(out))
```

test.txt:

```
homer,2
foo,1,2,3
bar,4,5,6
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('bar', deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)), ('foo', deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)), ('homer', deque([2], maxlen=3))])
OrderedDict([('bar', deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)), ('foo', deque([2, 3, 100], maxlen=3)), ('homer', deque([2], maxlen=3))])
OrderedDict([('bar', deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)), ('foo', deque([2, 3, 100], maxlen=3)), ('homer', deque([2], maxlen=3))])
```

Once sorted you just need to load to get the dict and dump after you have written.

Comment: Thanks man thats what I needed also i'd like to ask u another question i have another program that writes to this text file, and i'd like to save 3 numbers to one letter how would I do that ???? one again thanks

Comment: Do you mean add two more numbers?

Comment: is that one line or two?

Comment: 2 line i pressed enter by accident sry

Comment: Are you adding to existing data or creating completely new data?

Comment: adding to existing data

Comment: so for example `a 4` is one line? Do you also just want to keep the a max of three removing the oldest?

Comment: You could use a deque http://stackoverflow.com/a/28398840/2141635 with maxlen=3,  then append the new value and the oldest will be removed

Comment: (new programmer problems) I dont get the way they converse about the code, or the code in genral. could u explain how I could use this in my program

Comment: You should probably ask a new question, a full working example would be another full answer.

Comment: okay I'll try but I dont have a full working example so far my code saves a name and a score, and when u retake the test it just saves it under a name and score so
jo 12
jo 45
jo 67
each jo is on a diffrent line i want it to look like jo 12,45,67 and i want multiple people score to be saved on one file

Comment: A proper solution would involve writing to a tempfile and replacing the original file, really if you are adding values to a name and don't have duplicate names a smart approach would simply be to use a dict and pickle it using a deque as the value for each key/name. Then you simply need to unpickle and add the score with maxlen=3 you will always have at most 3 scores and always the latest

Comment: could you show me how ive been spending weeks with this problem and cant solve it.

Comment: I am heading out now  but will throw something together later or in the am

Comment: @lokirgrothgor, I added how to persist the data with pickle, I suggest you read the docs to get a good understanding of what is happening

Comment: Could you start a chat with me?? becuase I need a lot of help with my program

Comment: I was wondering If I could chat with u on some forum becuase I have to complete this task quickly for my teacher and am sooooo stuck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use readlines() instead of read() to get each line of the file as a seperate element of the list. Then a simple sort of the list will work.

```
f = open('1.txt','r')

# Use readlines isntead of of read to get an list of lines
lines = f.readlines()
print ''.join(lines)

# Now sort the list (default is by first letter
lines.sort()
print ''.join(lines)
```

Alternatively you could force the split function to use the end of line char '\n' instead of the default which is all white space. But now you will need to join the list back with the new line char ('\n') instead of an empty string.

```
f = open('1.txt','r')
lines = f.read()
lines = lines.split('\n')
print '\n'.join(lines)

# Now sort the list (default is by first letter
lines.sort()
print '\n'.join(lines)
```